# Seaborn: Place the y-label in a line with the points on the coordinate axis

Tags: seaborn

I want to place the y-label in the left upper corner in line with the points on the coordinate axis. The label should replace the axes ticks in that area.

Here is an example from a paper that I read:

[image]

I found a lot of information on how to move the label to the top left corner. However, how do I remove the ticks and move the label closer to the axes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that I found:

```py
# style
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
sns.set_style("white")
sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=1.6)

# plot
sn_dis1 = sns.displot(idx_pix_count_pd, hue='Dataset', x="Size", fill=True, palette='bwr', kind="hist", bins=500)

# y-achses
axes = sn_dis1.axes.flatten()
axes[0].set_ylabel("Count", fontsize=16)
axes[0].yaxis.set_label_coords(.0, .9)
```

[image]

The approach proposed by Trenton (Edit: Who delete his comment to my original question) did not work for me as the text is horizontal vertically. But I learned something from it and am sure that you somehow can make it work like that.

```py
# style
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
sns.set_style("white")
sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=1.6)

# plot
sn_dis1 = sns.displot(idx_pix_count_pd, hue='Dataset', x="Size", fill=True, palette='bwr', kind="hist", bins=500)

# y-achses
ticks = range(8) 
labels= list(range(7)) + ['Density'] 

axes = sn_dis1.axes.flatten()

axes[0].set_yticklabels(labels)

# do not show default label
axes[0].get_yaxis().get_label().set_visible(False)
```

[image]